# javascript canvas animate with setinterval or settimeout, reliable?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to animate leg of my space invader, but I have issues with settimeout.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldr8/10/

```
// Leg right
invadersContext.fillRect(init_x + pixel*5,init_y + pixel,pixel,pixel);
invadersContext.fillRect(init_x + pixel*5,init_y + pixel*2,pixel,pixel);
setTimeout(function(){invadersContext.fillRect(init_x + pixel*6,init_y + pixel*2,pixel,pixel);}, 3000);
setTimeout(function(){invadersContext.clearRect(init_x + pixel*6,init_y + pixel*2,pixel,pixel);}, 1500);
```

I don't understand why animation doesn't happen. Obviously I'm using setTimeout in a wrong way.

Somebody care to explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) and fallback to setTimeout/Interval if not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` waits *n milliseconds* and then runs the callback function, just once. You need to use `setInterval` instead:

```
var leftOrRight = "left";

setInterval(function(){
    if(leftOrRight == "left"){
        invadersContext.fillRect(init_x + pixel * 6, init_y + pixel * 2, pixel, pixel);
        leftOrRight = "right";
    }else{
        invadersContext.clearRect(init_x + pixel * 6, init_y + pixel * 2, pixel, pixel);
        leftOrRight = "left";
    }
}, 1000);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldr8/11/

Comment: Thanks! any ideas how to deal with color problem? look at legs: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldr8/18/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your delays sync up and the second overwrites the first. Instead of calling both you need to alternate like this:

```
var draw = true;

setInterval(function() {

    draw ?
        invadersContext.fillRect(init_x + pixel * 6, init_y + pixel * 2, pixel, pixel) :
        invadersContext.clearRect(init_x + pixel * 6, init_y + pixel * 2, pixel, pixel);

    draw = !draw;

}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/385Lr/1/

Comment: Hey, yep that makes sense. Any ideas how to deal with http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldr8/18/ leg color problem?

Comment: @salivan change the context fillStyle before filling the rect. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ldr8/19/

Comment: I swear I tried that before asking and it didn't seem to work. :| antihistaminic is dozing me of! thanks though +1.

Comment: @salivan The problem was that black was the last colour you set as the fillStyle, when you create the last space invader's body. Then the intervals for each invader are called _after_ that's been set so it remained black.